# Swift: How to stop Background music when changing views

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to get the background music to stop playing when changing to another view.

I have a global variable to play the music

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class MusicHelper {
    static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper()
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    func playBackgroundMusic() {
        let aSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "The Walking Dead", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:aSound as URL)
            audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
            audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer!.play()
        } catch {
            print("Cannot play the file")
        }
    }
}
```

And then I load the music into the view here

```
import UIKit
import SwiftGifOrigin
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    @IBOutlet weak var introGif: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Gif intro
        self.introGif.image = UIImage.gifWithName("WalkingDeadIntro")

        _ = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "WalkingDeadIntro", withExtension: "gif")!)
        //self.bottomImageView.image = UIImage.gif(data: imageData)

        // Load background Music
        MusicHelper.sharedHelper.playBackgroundMusic()
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with adding MusicHelper.sharedHelper.stopBackgroundMusic() to viewWillDisappear() for example?

Answer (score 0):

Just write below code to stop the player whenever view changes provided that audioPlayer is a global variable as you mentioned.

```
override func viewWillDisappear( ) {
audioPlayer.stop( )
}
```

Comment: Thats one way I tried earlier and got override can only be specified on class members

Comment: // Load background Music
        MusicHelper.sharedHelper.playBackgroundMusic(){
        
        override func viewWillDisappear( ) {
            audioPlayer!.stop( )
        }